# Rails Restforce - Unable to access custom fields / objects

Tags: custom-object, soap-api, custom-field, ruby, ruby-on-rails

Im using the [restforce gem](https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce) to access my salesforce data. Im receiving errors whenever i try to acess any custom fields or objects. For example:

I have a custom field `Gender` in my `Contact` object. Whenever i try to use edit this value via the following ruby code:

```
@client.update!(
    'Contact',
    Id: #{ID},
    Gender: #{Value},
)
```

I get the error: `INVALID_FIELD: No such Column 'Gender' on sobject type Contact`

Note: If I edit/read a `Contact` object without editing the `Gender` field, there are no problems.

Similarly, I have a custom object called Application, with a range of fields. If I try to create an Application in salesforce with the following code:

```
@client.create!(
  'Application',
  field: #{value}
)
```

I get the error `NOT_FOUND: requested resource does not exist`

Finally, if i try to run `client.picklist_values('Contact', 'Gender')`

I get the error `NoMethodError Exception: undefined method []' for nil:NilClass`

What is causing this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out - we are having the same issue.

Comment: @AbbyJones The name of my object and fields were incorrect. On salesforce go to setup, then search 'object'. Under 'Create' you should see 'Objects'. Here you can find the correct names for custom fields